# How to minimum value of any column corresponding to maximum value of other column in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have a data frame made of following csv file in spark sql,:

cust,bucket,freq

A,3,4

A,2,1

A,1,4

B,1,3

B,3,4

B,2,4

C,3,1

C,2,1

C,4,1

D,2,3

D,4,5

D,1,5

For every customer, I want minimum bucket number corresponding to maximum frequency. desired output :

cust,bucket

A,1

B,2

C,2

D,1

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks friends !!

Answer (score 3):

Window functions should help you. And the code should look like this:

```
val partitioner = Window.partionBy($"cust").orderBy($"freq", $"bucket" desc)
val partitionedDF = df.withColumn("numerator", rowNumber.over(partitioner))
//df is dataframe, which contains your data
partitionedDF.filter('numerator == 1)
```

I hope it would work

Comment: There's no column "A", I don't know why you are using it

Comment: Just one more: consider using `dropColumn(numerator)`, it is not necessary later. But answer is correct and should be accepted